# Why can not get the correct ids as expected if I input some string

Tags: python

**I have following file:**

Here, `id` is unique while `Name` might be repeatable

```
Name    id
Ajay    1
Ram     2
Ajay    3
Ram     4
Jack    6
Devid   7
```

**I write following program to make my aim: e.g.**

- if user enter name `ajay`, then program will return list of IDs `[1,3]`
- if user enter name `Ram`, the program will return list of IDs `[2,4]`

**My code:**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('hi')
    file1=open('data.txt','r')
    set1=[]
    for line in file1:
        line=line.strip()
        set2=list(line.split(' '))
        set1.append(set2)
    print(set1)
```

Why does it not work?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done very easily through python's library `pandas`:

```
In [1952]: df = pd.read_fwf('file.txt')

In [1953]: df
Out[1953]: 
    Name   id
0   Ajay  1.0
1  Ram 2  NaN
2   Ajay  3.0
3  Ram 4  NaN
4   Jack  6.0
5  Devid  7.0

In [1957]: df[df.Name == 'Ajay']['id'].tolist()
Out[1957]: [1.0, 3.0]
```

Just replace `Ajay` with a variable that you take input from user.

Code will be much cleaner and smaller. Let me know if this helps.